# The meaning of STALL

Tags: meaning

The sentence below comes from Longman dictionary.

> The ***stall*** took £25 on Saturday.
>
> http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/take

I don't know the meaning of STALL in ths context.

I check out a dictionary but there's so many meanings that I can't not specify exactly which meaning corresponds to this sentence in question.

Comment: do an image search for “market stall” on Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stall):

**NOUN 1.** A stand, booth, or compartment for the sale of goods in a market or large covered area.
‘fruit and vegetable stalls’

This particular stall sold £25 on Saturday.